# How to match a pattern with non capture group in JS regex

Tags: javascript, regex

All:

I am pretty new to Regex in JS, if I have a string like( of course not this simple, but this part is most important to me):

```
?view=Peer%20Comparison&&userid=123
```

I want to extract the "view=Peer%20Comparison" part with non-capture group and capture group(there may be multiple query parameter pairs)

Could anyone help me with this(I guess this is very simple to regex guru, but I just can not think out of any, sorry for interrupt)?

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by this `capture group(there may be multiple query parameter pairs)`? could you post a complex example?

Comment: You can use `split` and pass `?` as separator..

Comment: @Kuan: is there a particular reason why you want to omit capture groups?

Comment: @AvinashRaj What I want to do is extract the url query parameter pairs from url with non-capture and capture group skill.

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar What I want to do is extract the url query parameter pairs from url, and I want to learn how to use non-capture and capture group and apply them to the url to get query prameter key value pair.

Comment: @CommuSoft the parts I want to omit is that ? mark and && which seperate key-value pairs

Comment: Looks like you're trying to parse query parameters. Here's an SO answer for that question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/2482570

Comment: @mheiber Thanks, that definitely work, and I can also just simply use split if I really want to get job done, but I just want to learn how to use non-capture group to get the starting position after ? mark and use capture group to extract each key value pair.

Comment: you cannot get anything from a non-capture group. they are non-capturing. they are only used for grouping.

Comment: @akonsu That is exactly what I want. I do not want the ? mark, I only need to get the position which follow it(I just want to indicate ? as a position pattern and get what following it. I read some posts, it is called lookahead or something like that)

Answer (score 4):

Answering the OP question for the sake of knowledge, even known a solution was found.

The syntax for non capturing group in JavaScript regular expression is:

`(?:pattern)`

as stated in https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#grouping-back-references

Also you should take a look at the **lookahead assertions** (e.g. `x(?=y)` and `x(?!y)`) in the same page as it may help.